# Regular Expression to Find Spaces

Tags: regex, space

I have the following text = "superilustrado e de capa dura?", and I want to find all the spaces between words in the text. I am using the following expression = `[\\p{L}[:punct:]][[:space:]][\\p{L}[:punct:]]`. The expression works fine but it can find the space between the "e de". Does anybody know what is the problem with my regular expression?

Answer (score 28):

Spaces can be found simply by putting a space character in your regex.

Whitespace can be found with `\s`.

If you want to find whitespace between words, use the `\b` word boundary marker.

This would match a single space between two words:

```
"\b \b"
```

(The reason your match failed is that `\\p{L}` includes the character in a match.  Because `e` is only one character, it gets eaten up by the previous match and can't be matched for the space after `e`.  `\b` avoids this problem because it is a zero-width match.)

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense. However, when I use the expression with a text that has punctuation, "Já imaginou seu filho publicar um livro de verdade, superilustrado e de capa dura? Então, vá preparando a festa de lançamento deste bestseller! Seu filho vai ter um livro escrito e ilustrado por ele mesmo!", it doesn't find all the spaces. Is there a way to include another expression that takes care of punctuation?

Comment: @Aldo, why not just search for all the spaces in the string?  Are there other spaces that you don't want to match?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm not tracking, but why not just use [ ]?

Comment: I used stringVar.contains(" "). It works, but I have to experiment with the expressions: "\b \b" and "\s".

Answer (score 5):

```
// Setup
var testString = "How many spaces are there in this sentence?";

// Only change code below this line.

var expression = /\s+/g;  // Change this line

// Only change code above this line

// This code counts the matches of expression in testString
var spaceCount = testString.match(expression).length;
```